# How to solve tHDFS component issue in talend open studio for Big data

Tags: hadoop, replication, hdfs, talend, hortonworks-data-platform

I installed HortonWorks Sandbox 2.1 through Oracle VM Virtual Box and then I tried to follow an example using Talend's tHDFS component but am getting the following error:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/115961411938996992246/posts/JygQvMgwEBz?pid=6084505570738968834&oid=115961411938996992246

My job layout looks like [image: this].

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data Replication error in Hadoop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447743/data-replication-error-in-hadoop)

Comment: Instead of posting an image of the error block can you instead paste the red highlighted error message into a code formatted block in place of the linked image? I'm pretty sure the linked question above should solve your issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved in Oracle VM Virtual Box by following these steps:

1. Go to **File-- >Preferencs --- >Network**, Now select the **Host-Only Networks** and add the **VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter** and click OK.
   ([Details](https://plus.google.com/u/0/115961411938996992246/posts/VedtDJD2wW4?pid=6085500274286331842&oid=115961411938996992246).)
2. Now right click on HartonWorks Sandbox and then go to **Settings-- >Network**, now selected the **Host-Only Adapter** for the filed of **Attached to** and Click Ok.
   ([Details](https://plus.google.com/u/0/115961411938996992246/posts/VedtDJD2wW4?pid=6085500274527597074&oid=115961411938996992246).)
3. Now start the Server.

We follow these three steps then the issue in talend was resolved.